# python convert time from 25:00:00 to 01:00:00

Tags: python, time

I have a list of time strings and would like to convert 25:00:00 to 01:00:00 and 26:00:00 to 02:00:00, so that I can sort the time like:

```
sorted((time.strptime(d, "%H:%M:%S") for d in list_of_time[stop]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Not very clear, do you want a fixed number *24* to be subtracted from the time string or you are just willing to order the strings by time order? In the latter case you could use the *key* argument of *sorted* with a function to impose that ordering.

Comment: Do you want to replace the hour by module of 24? I.e. 25 -> 1, 50 -> 2, etc, only the output, while maintaining their order?